# XML image href edit with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I am trying to edit a XML file to put it into a graphic design program (indesign) and I want to use a value in the XML to get the attribute href with a XSLT file
XML is:

```
       <data>
          <PetShop_1>
            <Item>PetShop_1</Item>
            <Cod_RMS>424919</Cod_RMS>
            <Descricao_Produto>RACAO NHOCK CLASSIC 8KG</Descricao_Produto>  
<Imagem>file:///G:/Drives%20compartilhados/Marketing/DESIGN/Cria%c3%a7%c3%b5es%202021/Tabloides/Boxes%20e%20tags/Pedro%20Jordan/vistas/6490226.jpg</Imagem>
          </PetShop_1>
        </data>
```

And I would like to get a transformed version, specially the image element to get the href attribute from a value of the original XML, and if possible, group the tags inside a father element

```
<data>
    <PetShop_1>
        <Sistema>
            <Item>PetShop_1</Item>
            <Cod_RMS>424919</Cod_RMS>
            <Descricao_Produto>RACAO NHOCK CLASSIC 8KG</Descricao_Produto> 
        </Sistema>
        <Imagem href="file:///G:/Drives%20compartilhados/Marketing/DESIGN/Cria%c3%a7%c3%b5es%202021/Tabloides/Boxes%20e%20tags/Pedro%20Jordan/vistas/6490226.jpg"></Imagem>
    </PetShop_1>
</data>
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Help you with what? You haven't started anything. Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

The following XSLT achieves the desired results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <!--default processing is to copy all attributes and nodes, 
        unless there are more specific matching templates to override that behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="PetShop_1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--add the Sistema element and group most content under it-->
            <Sistema>
                <!--do the normal copy for all elements except for Imagem -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="* except Imagem"/>
            </Sistema>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Imagem"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--change the Imagem text() into an attribute named href -->
    <xsl:template match="Imagem/text()">
        <xsl:attribute name="href" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And if I would like to create a new group called "Product" with the tags "Item" and "Cod RMS"?  I could use:  <!--add the Product element-->
            <Product>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Item; Cod_RMS "/>
            </Product>

Comment: Yes, but the select would be `select="Item|Cod_RMS"` or `select="(Item,Cod_RMS)"` (using the `|` union operator, or just a sequence of child elements to select)